# Bluetooth “out of band” (OOB) pairing on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7, bluetooth, out-of-band

Is there a way to read the local OOB data from the Bluetooth chip under Windows 7?

I would like to use out-of-band pairing and have currently no clue, how to get the simple pairing hash C and randomizer R.

Btw, I'm currently using C++ and the Windows BT Stack.

Comment: [Stollmann SDK](http://www.stollmann.de/en/stacks/bluetooth-bluetooth-low-energy.html) can do this on Win7